# Receiving a SystemFault when I query Item

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using V3 when I attempt to query for Items I receive a generic error with a `SystemFault` type.

I am attempting to perform `Select * From Item Where Name = 'Something'`

This **does** work in the API Explorer, and I believe I am re-creating the HTTP request accurately.

My `HTTP GET` is:

```
GET /v3/company/redacted/query?query=Select%20*%20From%20Item%20Where%20Name%20=%20'Something'%20STARTPOSITION%201%20MAXRESULTS%2020 HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/xml
Accept-Encoding gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Authorization   OAuth oauth_consumer_key="redacted", oauth_nonce="redacted", oauth_signature="redacted", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1386704546", oauth_token="redacted", oauth_version="1.0"
Host    qb.sbfinance.intuit.com
```

And the response I am receiving:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-12-10T11:42:03.147-08:00">
    <Fault type="SystemFault">
        <Error code="10000">
            <Message>An application error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
            <Detail>System Failure Error: Unexpected Internal Error. (-30000)</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not obvious, but from the [documentation found here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations), it looks like you must encode the `'` and `=` present on your query.

So instead of:

> /v3/company/redacted/query?query=Select%20*%20From%20Item%20Where%20Name%20=%20'Something'%20STARTPOSITION%201%20MAXRESULTS%2020

You should use

> /v3/company/redacted/query?query=Select%20*%20From%20Item%20Where%20Name%20%3D%20%27Something%27%20STARTPOSITION%201%20MAXRESULTS%2020

Encoding ' to %27, and = to %3D.